# How can you add attributes to title tags?

Tags: magento-1.9, page-title

Is there a way to have the manufacturer or color attribute when you select these attributes from our sidebar? So it would be like, you clicked "Sony" and are now on a Sony page of products. So the  tag would then be "Sony | Our Company Name" or "Black | Sony | Our Company Name" because you then clicked "black" from our sidebar?

Is this possible? Right now we have a ton of duplicate titles that I've never noticed until now.

Comment: Is "Sony"  as category or product attribute ?

Comment: It's an attribute as "manufacturer"

Comment: is it dropdown or multi select or text attribute?

Comment: Manufacturer is a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Magento set product page title using `mete_title` field of product.

First read ,a great example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869335/magento-change-product-page-titles-to-include-attributes

**There are 3 way to set this meta title is product page:**

**1.** Update `mete_title` field by magento default mass product import
    system

**2.** Rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` and override the `_prepareLayout()` method which responsible for product title.

**3.** using `event/observer` change the title.For product page use

```
catalog_controller_product_view.
```

for getting the manufacturer field value try this code

```
  $productObject->getAttributeText('manufacturer')
```